# Normwise Relative Error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I have 2 vectors $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$. Here, $\textbf{x}$ contains my 'exact' solution data and $\textbf{y}$ is approximated vector. I want to calculate normwise relative error which defined as
$E_{r}=\frac{\lVert \textbf{x}-\textbf{y} \rVert_{2}}{\lVert \textbf{y} \rVert_{2}} $.
How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: This question is purely about how to implement something in matlab and should therefore be asked on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x` and `y` are two Matlab vectors with the same size and `y` is nonzero, then

```
Er = norm(x-y)./norm(y)
```

computes $\|$`x`$-$`y`$\|_2/\|$`y`$\|_2$.

Comment: Small remark, as this might cause confusion: the `.` is not necessary.

Comment: @Harry49 Thank you for your response, this answer has solved my problem. Philipp Siehr: I'm so sorry for wrong categorisation and thanks for your remark!